# Prove that there there are two $a,b$ so $f''(a)=f''(b)=0$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

Let $f$ be a function that can be derived twice. We know that $f$ is even function and has local minimum at $x=2$. Prove that there there are two $a,b$ so $f''(a)=f''(b)=0$.

I think that I need to use the Rolle's theorem here but after trying for one hour, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f$ has a local minimum at $-2$ also. Any even differentiable functions satisfies $f'(0)=0$. Thus $f'(-2)=f'(0)=f'(2)=0$. Can you finish?

I am assuming that the domain of your function is $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true. Let:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
(x+2)^2 \ \ \text{if} \ \ x\in(-2-\frac12,-2+\frac12) \\
(x-2)^2 \ \ \text{if} \ \ x\in(2-\frac12,2+\frac12)
\end{cases}
$$

Where:
$f:(-2-\frac12,-2+\frac12) \cup (2-\frac12,2+\frac12) \to \mathbb{R}$